{ configureapplicationcookie } options do not change LogoutPath, LoginPath, Cookie.name and AccessDeniedPath
I have a strange story when I used it for the first time, it worked, but after that I don't know what happened. The problem occurs when you change the path for LoginPath, LogoutPath, AccessDeniedPath, and the name of the cookie. using asp .net core 8.0
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("cookie").AddCookie("cookie");

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/LogOut");
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/AccessDenied");
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

After research there is shorter version of the same result of this and not working

builder.Services.AddAuthentication("cookie").AddCookie("cookie", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "Cookie";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
    options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/LogOut");
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/AccessDenied");
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});

I am using AddIdentity  as
builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore<User, IdentityRole, AppDbContext, string>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserEmailStore<User>, UserStore<User, IdentityRole, AppDbContext, string>>();

If the user not authorized (log out) If I go to endpoint that have authorize notation the application Should go to the preconfigure path for login
as http://localhost:5204/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Farea%2Findex
But it go to
http://localhost:5204/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Farea%2Findex
Likewise with AccessDeniedPath , LogoutPath and cookie.Name
cookie name should be cookie but it is .AspNetCore.Identity.Application
As my understanding this is the default configuration for the cookie aka authenticationScheme
Controller endpoint
                [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login(string ReturnUrl = null)
        {
            // Your logic here
        }


        [HttpPost]
    
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModelView model, string? ReturnUrl)
        {
            // Your logic here
        }

I tried to change the order of two services AddIdentity AddAuthentication also not working ,
Also try this same result
builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).Ad...


Ok i have the answers the problem was i am using AddIdentity and when i have do my research i figured that AddIdentity and AddDefaultIdentity has its own configuration and not Customizable Instead that use AddIdentityCore As it can be customized as you want
** Note if anyone is reading this and there is any mistake in what I said, I would be grateful for correcting me
builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<User>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
})
    // If You Need To Add The IdentityRole
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    //This is for provides methods to create, update, delete, and query
    //Aka 
    //    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    //    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;
    //    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
    .AddRoleStore<RoleStore<IdentityRole, AppDbContext, string>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
    .AddUserManager<UserManager<User>>()
    .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()
    .AddUserStore<UserStore<User, IdentityRole, AppDbContext, string>>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();


builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserEmailStore<User>, UserStore<User, IdentityRole, AppDbContext, string>>();


// Add authentication services and configure cookie settings
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = "Identity.Application";
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "Identity.Application";
})
.AddCookie("Identity.Application", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "YourCookieName";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    //options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
    //options.Cookie.MaxAge = options.ExpireTimeSpan;
    options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/LogOut");
    options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/AccessDenied");
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
});


